# Get all attachments (photos) from a post through Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I know a [way](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/story_attachment) to get the attachments by Graph API. But this can only get 12 items back. I don't see an edge like "next page" in the JSON, how should I do this?

Comment: File a bug developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 3):

In my case,

```
/{page-id}/feed/?fields=message,attachments{subattachments.limit(30)}
```

Here, 30 is big enough for limit. (Maybe default limit is 12.)